# NDESK Command line parsing in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parsing, command-line, parameters

Although I tried many times, I can't translate the NDESK.Options parsing example into a simple vb.net code (sorry I'm not a pro).

The only example they provide is available here: 
http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html

however, I do not understand this crucial part of the code:

```
var p = new OptionSet () {
        { "n|name=", "the {NAME} of someone to greet.",
          v => names.Add (v) },
        { "r|repeat=", 
            "the number of {TIMES} to repeat the greeting.\n" + 
                "this must be an integer.",
          (int v) => repeat = v },
        { "v", "increase debug message verbosity",
          v => { if (v != null) ++verbosity; } },
        { "h|help",  "show this message and exit", 
          v => show_help = v != null },
    };
```

this part: v => names.Add (v) gets the following vb.net equivalent: 
Function(v) names.Add (v), 
which I don't get.

Can anyone be so kind and post it in a more understandable set of commands?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the VB.NET version of the code above for NDesk.Options OptionSet object. 
This code example uses collection initializers.

```
Static names = New List(Of String)()
Dim repeat As Integer
Dim verbosity As Integer
Dim show_help As Boolean = False

Dim p = New OptionSet() From {
 {"n|name=", "the {NAME} of someone to greet.", _
     Sub(v As String) names.Add(v)}, _
 {"r|repeat=", _
     "the number of {TIMES} to repeat the greeting.\n" & _
     "this must be an integer.", _
     Sub(v As Integer) repeat = v}, _
 {"v", "increase debug message verbosity", _
     Sub(v As Integer) verbosity = If(Not IsNothing(v), verbosity + 1, verbosity)}, _
 {"h|help", "show this message and exit", _
     Sub(v) show_help = Not IsNothing(v)}
 }
```

This code example creates OptionSet collection and then adds each option calling Add method. Also, Notice the last option is an example of passing function pointer (AddressOf) of your function.

```
Static names = New List(Of String)()
Dim repeat As Integer
Dim verbosity As Integer
Dim show_help As Boolean = False

Dim p = New OptionSet()
p.Add("n|name=", "the {NAME} of someone to greet.", _
            Sub(v As String) names.Add(v))
p.Add("r|repeat=", _
            "the number of {TIMES} to repeat the greeting.\n" & _
            "this must be an integer.", _
            Sub(v As Integer) repeat = v)
p.Add("v", "increase debug message verbosity", _
            Sub(v As Integer) verbosity = If(Not IsNothing(v), verbosity + 1, verbosity))
p.Add("h|help", "show this message and exit", _
            Sub(v) show_help = Not IsNothing(v))
' you can also pass your function address to Option object as an action.
' like this:
p.Add("f|callF", "Call a function.", New Action(Of String)(AddressOf YourFunctionName ))
```

Comment: I used this and it worked, 99%. The key thing I was missing was `p.Parse(args)`. For some reason I thought this library worked automagically and it knew that args would be passed in and parse it automatically.

Comment: The other thing I was missing was `n|name=` when defining the parameters. I didn't realize the `=` was what I needed in order to have an argument that has a value.